# Some PDFs do not snap to the window while using Preview

Tags: macos, pdf, preview, zoom

I have a ton of college textbooks in PDF form, and I use Preview hours on end, every day; so this little problem becomes quite annoying:

Some of my PDF files "snap" to the size of the window when I open them, and will stick to the size of the window as I resize it to my desired level of zoom (below, left).

[image]
[image]

However, some PDF files do not adhere to this behavior, and I will have to resort to manually adjust the zoom level. This also becomes annoying since if I manually choose a zoom level, even though the file still fits in the window, both scrollbars become active i.e. as I scroll up and down the document, my scrolling skews to the left and right constantly (above, right).

I have Acrobat Pro on my computer, and I have tried to find the right property to change, but to no avail. Does anyone have any fixes for this/ or knows what property I should be hunting for in Acrobat?

Comment: Just to address your last line, in general posts on the SE network discourage hello, thank you, and any other customary courtesy sayings in order to make the discussion clearer and to the point. Just for your reference in the future!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the document.

Typically, documents are set at 100%, so no matter the size of the window, it will automatically resize to fit the window.

However, the *actual* page size may be set to a different value when it was created so, when opening, it starts at that value.

From [Adjusting PDF Views](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/adjusting-pdf-views.html)

> The actual size for a PDF page is typically 100%, but the document may
>   have been set to another magnification level when it was created.

Since you have Acrobat Pro, try creating a new PDF document and set the page properties to be at 100%.